# How to move file with in Batch Script basing the result from XMLStarlet

Tags: batch-file

I have a situation where, I use XML STARTLET to validate a bunch of XML files each time and would like to perform further actions

- If XML is invalid, Move the file to a specific directory and to print it in the logs
- If XML is valid, rename the file with a specific timestamp and move the file the file to a specific directory.

The following script, I coded so far to achieve the actions basing the result from XML validations does not seem to function. I believe the usage of two for loops seem to cause the further script to not to function as needed. Can someone take a look and advice on how I shall proceed?

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "xmlStarletLocation=D:\tools\xmlstarlet"
SET "SourceXMLDirectory=D:\PH01"
SET "SourceXML=ProductData.xml"
SET "SourceXSDDirectory=D:\dtd"
SET "InvalidXMLDirectory=D:\PH01Invalid"
SET "TargetXMLDirectory=D:\PH01_ISH"
SET "ArchiveDirectory=D:\PH01_saved"
SET "LogDirectory=D:\validationLogs"

:TIMESTAMP:
TIMEOUT 1 > NUL  
FOR /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a IN ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') DO SET "dt=%%a"
SET "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & SET "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & SET "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & SET "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
SET "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & SET "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & SET "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
SET "FullStamp=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
SET "TargetFileName=ProductData%FullStamp%.xml"

:VALIDATOR:
CD %SourceXMLDirectory%
:VALIDATOR:
FOR  %%i in (*ProductData*.xml) DO (
    FOR /f "eol=: delims=" %%A IN ('%xmlStarletLocation%\xml val -e -s %SourceXSDDirectory%\ProductData.xsd %SourceXMLDirectory%\%%i') >>%LOGFILE% DO (SET "ln=%%A"
        IF "!ln:~-8!" == " invalid" (
            MOVE  "%SourceXMLDirectory%\%%i" "%InvalidXMLDirectory%\%%i"
            ECHO %%i Validation failed. Check %LogDirectory%\ProductDataLog.txt for the logs. 1>&2
        )if "!ln:~-6!" == " valid" (
            MOVE /y "%SourceXMLDirectory%\%%i" "%TargetXMLDirectory%\%TargetFileName%"
            ECHO File is valid and uploaded to %TargetXMLDirectory%
        )
    )
)
:EOF:
```

The >> is not allowed at this time.

```
D:\cmd>CD D:\ProductExport
>> was unexpected at this time.
D:\ProductExport>        FOR /f "eol=: delims=" %A IN ('D:\tools\xmlstarlet\xml val -e -s D:\ProductData.xsd D:\ProductExport\%i') >>  DO (
```

Comment: Why don't you just replace your entire content of the `:TIMESTAMP:` section, with `For /F "EOL=L" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe OS Get LocalDateTime') Do If Not "%%~xG" == "" Set "TargetFileName=%TargetXMLDirectory%\ProductData%%~nG.xml"`?

Comment: or use powershell to get a fomatted date `for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('PowerShell -Command "& {Get-Date -format 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'}"') do set "TargetFileName=ProductData%%~i.xml"` I am also not convinced that the space at the end of the line here is a good thing, also use double quotes. `('"%xmlStarletLocation%\xml" val -e -s "%SourceXSDDirectory%\ProductData.xsd" "%SourceXMLDirectory%\%%i"')`

Comment: With some of the help available here, I managed to get the XSD validations through. But I am now stuck with the Logging part. The >>%LOGFILE% is being complained as an issue and is not expected at this time. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Here is my code: `:VALIDATOR:
FOR  %%i in (*ProductData*.xml) DO (  
FOR /f "eol=: delims=" %%A IN ('%xmlStarletLocation%\xml val -e -s %SourceXSDDirectory%\ProductData.xsd %SourceXMLDirectory%\%%i') >>%LOGFILE% DO (SET "ln=%%A"  
  IF "!ln:~-8!" == " invalid" (
  MOVE  "%SourceXMLDirectory%\%%i" "%InvalidXMLDirectory%\%%i"
  ECHO %%i Validation failed. Check %LogDirectory%\ProductDataLog.txt for the logs. 1>&2
  )if "!ln:~-6!" == " valid" (
  MOVE /y "%SourceXMLDirectory%\%%i" "%TargetXMLDirectory%\%TargetFileName%" 
  ECHO File is valid and uploaded to %TargetXMLDirectory% 
)
)
)`

Comment: @Tester, I have added the code from your comment above to your question. Please delete that comment, and then correct any differences between what I read and what your actual code looks like wirth regards line returns and whitespace.

Comment: @Compo, You read my code correct. I have the changes made with in the previous code. Can you check it now?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is to remove `@ECHO OFF` from the first line of your script, then Open a Command Prompt window, and run your script from there. You should then see every command being run, and any error messages etc. If you cannot work out from the output what is happening, post all of it, as formatted code, into your question area, and we'll try to assist you.

Comment: @Compo, you have the error messages now. Can you check?

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window, type `for /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key, and read the syntax and usage information. You should notice the the syntax is `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ([file-set|"string"|'command']) DO command`, not `FOR /F ["options"] %variable IN ([file-set|"string"|'command']) >>[file|device] DO command`.

Comment: Okay, Any suggestion on where I can put in the command to get the logs captured from the XSD validation to a log file?